# ASP.Net Web API: How to achieve url parameter and attribute based versioning with same Controller methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to achieve url parameter and attribute based versioning with same Controller methods. To explain that, suppose I have one controller like,

```
[RoutePrefix("api/{apiVersion:apiVersionConstraint(v2)}/values")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/v2/values
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "v2-value1", "v2-value2" };
    }

    // GET api/v2/values/5
    [Route("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "v2-value-" + id;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to access the API endpoint by both of the following URL's:

http://hostname/context/api/v1/values

http://hostname/context/api/values?v=1

Is it possible?

N.B. I'm using the example at [WebApiNamespaceVersion](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/WebApiNamespacesVersion) in GitHub

Comment: 'v' means version ? so where is 'id' in second method?

Comment: Technically it is possible but there are different ways to achieve that.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh can you please elaborate some way to do this. I was trying to intercept the `request` before it's getting into the route filters, by overriding the `SendAsync` of `DelegateHandler`. But that seems to be going completely out of the default in app route mechanism.